# NDSolve solves for two equations but not for three

Tags: differential-equations

I have to solve a system of ODE

$\sum_{i=1}^N \dot{w}_i^{}\,q_i^k+w_i\,k\,q^{k-1}_i\,\dot{q}^{}_i=
\sum_{i=1}^N k\,f(q_i^{},t)\,q^{k-1}_i+k(k-1)\,\varepsilon(q_i^{},t)\,q^{k-2}_i\,,\quad k=0...2N-1$

that could be rewritten as

$\sum_{i=1}^N (1-k)\dot{w}_i^{}\,q_i^k+k\,q^{k-1}_i\,\dot{\xi}^{}_i=
\sum_{i=1}^N k\,f(q_i^{},t)\,q^{k-1}_i+k(k-1)\,\varepsilon(q_i^{},t)\,q^{k-2}_i\,,\quad k=0...2N-1$

by expanding the second term at LHS after letting $\xi_i=w_i\,q_i$.

For two equations (n=2) the code

```
n = 2;
f[q_, t_] := Sin[2 π q];
ε[q_, t_] := 0.01;
wvar = Table[Subscript[w, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
ξvar = Table[Subscript[ξ, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
qvar = Table[
   Subscript[ξ, i][t] == 
    Subscript[w, i][t] Subscript[q, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
var = Flatten@{wvar, ξvar};
dyn = Table[
   Sum[(1 - k) D[Subscript[w, i][t], t] Subscript[q, i][t]^k + 
      k Subscript[q, i][t]^(k - 1) D[Subscript[ξ, i][t], t], {i, 
      1, n}] == 
    Sum[k Subscript[q, i][t]^(k - 1) f[Subscript[q, i][t], t] + 
      k (k - 1) Subscript[q, i][t]^(
       k - 2) ε[Subscript[q, i][t], t], {i, 1, n}], {k, 
    0, 2 n - 1}];
sys = Flatten@{dyn, qvar, Subscript[w, 1][0] == 0.5, 
    Subscript[w, 2][0] == 0.5, Subscript[q, 1][0] == 0.1, 
    Subscript[q, 2][0] == 0.15};
sol = NDSolveValue[sys, var, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate@sol[[1 ;; n]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate@(sol[[n + 1 ;; 2 n]]/sol[[1 ;; n]]), {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

works fine. But for three equations (n=3)

```
n = 3;
f[q_, t_] := Sin[2 π q];
ε[q_, t_] := 0.01;
wvar = Table[Subscript[w, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
ξvar = Table[Subscript[ξ, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
qvar = Table[
   Subscript[ξ, i][t] == 
    Subscript[w, i][t] Subscript[q, i][t], {i, 1, n}];
var = Flatten@{wvar, ξvar};
dyn = Table[
   Sum[(1 - k) D[Subscript[w, i][t], t] Subscript[q, i][t]^k + 
      k Subscript[q, i][t]^(k - 1) D[Subscript[ξ, i][t], t], {i, 
      1, n}] == 
    Sum[k Subscript[q, i][t]^(k - 1) f[Subscript[q, i][t], t] + 
      k (k - 1) Subscript[q, i][t]^(
       k - 2) ε[Subscript[q, i][t], t], {i, 1, n}], {k, 
    0, 2 n - 1}];
sys = Flatten@{dyn, qvar, Subscript[w, 1][0] == 0.333333, 
    Subscript[w, 2][0] == 0.333333, Subscript[w, 3][0] == 0.333333, 
    Subscript[q, 1][0] == 0.1, Subscript[q, 2][0] == 0.15, 
    Subscript[q, 3][0] == 0.9};
sol = NDSolveValue[sys, var, {t, 0, 1}]
```

NDSolve/NDSolveValue does not provide the solution. I tried also to go back to the original formulation, i.e. without the $\xi_i$'s, but still Mathematica cannot compute the solution, it simply hangs forever.

Any guess why?

Thanks,

Fabio

Comment: When I used exact values throughout (e.g., 1/10 vice 0.1)  I get the error message "NDSolveValue::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions."

Comment: @BobHanlon what version do you have? I cannot reproduce the issue by changing the initial datum to exact values.

Comment: "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)"